# AMP pages appear in Google Desktop search results

Tags: google-search, amp

I'm using WordPress on my website. To add the AMP pages to my website I use the official WordPress AMP plugin and another plugin called "AMP for WP". I've been using it for 3 months now. Recently, I discovered a Non-AMP page while searching Google from Laptop (Not mobile device). I checked the page source and found that the rel-canonical tag is properly set to the non-AMP page. I don't know why it appeared in the desktop search.

To see the example google this "how to change Author box gravatar size" and you'll find the AMP page and the non-AMP page doesn't appear.

Where is the problem?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't quite get what you're asking. This is the way that AMP pages are made

Comment: Now the 2 pages (both AMP & non-AMP) appear in the SERPs, is there anything wrong with that? I mean, will Google consider it as a duplicate content? my site is wp-me.com you'll find it in the results.

Comment: no, it will not affect your SEO in any way as the canonical links are the same

Answer (score 1):

AMP as a platform has been designed to provide faster and better experience. Pages load very fast and smoothly. 
Having said that, if you make a search using your desktop then google search would display the desktop version of your page and not the amp version. AMP pages are only to be displayed when the search has been made using the mobile device.

To make you understand better the co-relation between amp and html pages, I am pasting relevant text from [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec).

> The mechanism described below provides a standardized way for software
>   to discover whether an AMP version exists for a canonical(HTML)
>   document.
>
> If an AMP document exists that is an alternative representation of a
>   canonical document, then the canonical document should point to the
>   AMP document via a link tag with the relation "amphtml".
>
> Example:
>
> The AMP
>   document itself is expected to point back to its canonical document
>   via a link tag with the relation "canonical".
>
> Example:
>
> `<link rel="canonical"
>   href="https://www.example.com/url/to/canonical/document.html">` (If a
>   single resource is simultaneously the AMP and the canonical document,
>   the canonical relation should point to itself--no "amphtml" relation
>   is required.)